# How to hide a class method within the same package

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

So I have a package called ABC with class A, class B and class C. Now my main class is outside the package and calls a Class A method called show() which is a public static method. Basically Class A acts like a gateway for package ABC. Now I have class C extend class B and I have an abstract  method called execute() in class B thats been overridden in class C. Now the access modifier for execute() is protected. Now I can't access execute() from main which is what I want but I can still access it from Class A because it's inside the same package. How can I hide execute inside the same package, i.e how do I hide execute() in Class A but still be able to access it in Class C?

Comment: you could push B and C a packeage level down deeper say ABC.BC

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java does not have the corresponding visibility modifiers, protected is a superset of package-private.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can hide the `execute()` from class A is to make it `private` in class C. But since the `execute()` is an abstract method in class B, this combination is illegal (`private` + `abstract`). Even if you make it protected, you can't override it and make it `private` in the class B, like in this example:

```
abstract class B 
{
 protected abstract void execute(); 
}
```

and :

```
class C
{
 @Override
 private void execute() {} // not working
}
```

Because it's illegal to assign a weaker access privileges when you override a method.